# Alternative to CROSS APPLY when fetching specific rows from joined table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables: `OrderItem` and `SkuPrice`.

`OrderItem` holds, as you might guess, details of an item (a SKU) on an order. There is a single entry per SKU per order in the `OrderItem` table.

`SkuPrice` holds prices for a SKU. There can be multiple entries per SKU. Each entry has an `EffectiveFromUtc` value (a date-and-time when the price becomes effective) and some entries may also have an `EffectiveToUtc` value denoting that the price is transient (this is used for temporary markdowns). SkuPrice also has a flag `IsCostPrice` to tell us whether an entry is for a cost or retail price.

I've joined these tables (and also the Order table) in a query to establish the full price, markdown price if any), and cost price for each SKU in the `OrderItem` table. I've used `OUTER APPLY` and `CROSS APPLY` to achieve the result I need... but the query is far from efficient (see below).

It feels to me like I should be doing this differently. Any ideas on a better approach?

Note that 'full price' is the most recent price that does not have an EffectiveToUtc date (cost price is the same, but the `IsCostPrice` flag must be `TRUE`)

```
SELECT      CustomerOrder.Id AS OrderId, CustomerOrder.DatePlacedUtc, OrderItem.Id As OrderItem, OrderItem.Sku, 
        TempPrice.Value AS TempPrice,
        OrderItem.ItemRetailPrice
FROM        [dbo].[Order] CustomerOrder JOIN OrderItem ON CustomerOrder.Id = OrderItem.OrderId
        OUTER APPLY
        (
            SELECT  Sku, Value, NetValue, VatRate
            FROM    SkuPrice (NOLOCK)
            WHERE   IsCostPrice = 0
                AND EffectiveFromUtc <= CustomerOrder.DatePlacedUtc
                AND EffectiveToUtc > CustomerOrder.DatePlacedUtc
                AND Sku = OrderItem.Sku
        ) TempPrice
        CROSS APPLY
        (
            SELECT  TOP 1 Sku, Value, NetValue, VatRate
            FROM    SkuPrice (NOLOCK)
            WHERE   IsCostPrice = 0
                AND Sku = OrderItem.Sku
                AND EffectiveFromUtc <= CustomerOrder.DatePlacedUtc
                AND EffectiveToUtc IS NULL
            ORDER BY EffectiveFromUtc DESC

        ) FullPrice
        CROSS APPLY
        (
            SELECT  TOP 1 Sku, Value, NetValue, VatRate
            FROM    SkuPrice (NOLOCK)
            WHERE   IsCostPrice = 1
                AND Sku = OrderItem.Sku
                AND EffectiveFromUtc <= CustomerOrder.DatePlacedUtc
                AND EffectiveToUtc IS NULL
            ORDER BY EffectiveFromUtc DESC
        ) CostPrice

WHERE       CustomerOrder.OrderStatusId >= 20 AND CustomerOrder.OrderStatusId < 200
ORDER BY    CustomerOrder.Id ASC, OrderItem.Sku ASC
```

Comment: Well, your cross applies I guess could be reworked as `exists` clauses (since you don't use them in your select or where clauses). Your outer apply could be a left join (all applies can be reworded as a join, though sometimes they can look uglier as a result), but it likely won't make much of a difference to your query's performance. EDIT: If you're experiencing performance issues, I'd suggest looking through the execution plan and figuring out what's slowing you down and whether decent indexing could improve that.

Comment: I see no reason to be using CROSS or OUTER APPLY in this case.  APPLY is generally used when calling user defined functions that require parameters passed in.  i would have written this query using 1 or more CTEs rather than using APPLY

Comment: What I ended up doing was two things: a) Create a second table for price, holding denormalised price data for each SKU with one record for each point in time when an element of price changed. b) Constructed the query using CTEs